# Dynamic building layout using PHP or C#

Tags: c#, php, image, mapping

I am trying to put together a solution for our office to map the cubicle and office layout. We currently have both php and C# applications, so the solution can be built in either. We have something in PHP already, that allows us to move people from one cubicle to another, but it is based off a static image size and point coordinates. For example, cubicle one is at (3px, 4px). While this solution is working, it doesn't allow for the image size to change, or for the image to change at all without significant coding to realign all of the points on the image. Is there a better solution that can be used or an open source library that would be helpful? A coworked suggested that the Google Maps API might be helpful, or Leaflet.js. However, these both use geocoding, so unless our current Lat and Long is accurate to like a foot, I don't see how these could help.

Thanks for any suggestions.

**Update**
Here is an image similar to the one we are using. We add absolutely positioned clickable divs over the image to show who sits there.

[image]

Comment: visio on a shared drive?

Comment: Would you share a screenshot of what you need? I have some really good ideas I'd like to share with you.

Comment: Leaflet.js doesn't require the use of Lat/Long, just use `L.CRS.Simple` http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icrs

Comment: Is WPF an option for you? or maybe silverlight? I could create an example in 20 minutes allowing to to click and drag items, rotate / scale the image, etc.

Comment: @HighCore - WPF is an option. In fact, we are trying to deprecate all of the PHP applications, so it would probably be preferable. The only thing is it has to integrate into a Sharepoint site (currently we use an iframe for php stuff)

Comment: @Mike then WPF is not an option, but Silverlight is. I have no experience integrating SL applications into sharepoint but I'm 100% sure it's possible. WPF is a desktop technology, you won't be able to easily put in in say a SharePoint Web Part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your co-worker suggested is not so much the GMaps API itself but the implementations of rotations/geosync translation/zoom algorithms that would allow you to flip an image and all the points related to the image.

No specific code implementation, so I can't be more specific.